# Defining projection of raster file which lacks prj file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap

I have two raster data. They must cover each other. My problem is, one of them doesen't have prj file, therefore I don't know what is the projection of this one. I can not cover this raster with the other one. Of course, I tried define projection function several times, but I don't know which projection should I use.

I use ArcMap 10.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [*Define Projection*](https://gisgeography.com/arcgis-projections-define-project/) tool in ArcGIS? It doesn't modify anything to the original file, just updates the projection information!